# Backend search term/keywords position order

Tags: magento-1.9, backend, search-terms

If i want to search for this product:

- iPhone 6 Mobile Phone special edition

I can now only find it by searching it like this: "iPhone 6 Mobile"

I want to be able to find it like this: "Mobile 6 iPhone", because some product names have their words ordered differently, so magento isn't showing even half of all the products because it just needs a too much specific search term.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to System=>Configuration=>Catalog=>Catalog Search=>Search Type and select option Combine (Like and Fulltext) and save..

You will be able to search irrespective of term position

Comment: This doesn't seem to have an effect on the desired result. It just doesn't give the same results as using e.g. "iPhone 6 Mobile" I would expect the search engine of magento, when using LIKE, and adjusting OR to AND, give results no matter what the term position is. I wonder how this query is build so that it only returns results in a specific term position order.